# difference between <mvc:annotation /> and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter bean

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

i was working on the spring - mvc. and we were using AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter bean declaration in *-servlet.xml file. As we were exploring Spring REST we came across  ... is there any difference and which is better to use. Can someone answer please ?

Answer (score 2):

The `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag registers, amongs other things, a `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` or if you are on Spring 3.1+ a `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. It will register a whole lot more and saves you from explicitly defining all that beans. (If you are on Spring 3.1 or up I strongly urge you to remove the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and to use the more powerful and flexible `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`).

What is all registered and how to customize it is explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable).